# prove a non-strict inequality using the triangle inequality

Tags: epsilon-delta, triangle-inequality

In an $\varepsilon - \  \delta $ delta proof I had to show that  $$|x^3+y^3|\leq 2(x^2+y^2)^{3/2}$$ i tried some things already such as splitting it but i cannot seem to figure out how to show this. Note: i had to write from the left side untill i arrive at the right side.

Comment: what do you want in form of a $\varepsilon - \delta$

Comment: @AdityaDwivedi i have to show that a x,y function is continious at a certain point and to do so i need to show this( it was also given as a hint in the exercise to use this)

Answer (score 0):

What about squaring both sides?
\begin{align*}
|x^{3} + y^{3}| \leq 2(x^{2} + y^{2})^{3/2} & \Longleftrightarrow x^{6} + 2x^{3}y^{3} + y^{6} \leq 4(x^{2} + y^{2})^{3}\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow x^{6} + 2x^{3}y^{3} + y^{6} \leq 4(x^{6} + 3x^{4}y^{2} + 3x^{2}y^{4} + y^{6})\\\\
& \Longleftrightarrow 3(x^{6} + y^{6}) + 10x^{4}y^{2} + 10x^{2}y^{4} + 2x^{2}y^{2}(x^{2} - xy + y^{2})\geq 0
\end{align*}

where the last inequality is true indeed.